# How to determine and find resource section in PE file?

Tags: winapi, portable-executable

How to find starting offset of resource section in PE file ?

```
BOOL IsResource(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Input){



}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear (do you want to check an address as being a resource, or find a resource -- the code example suggests something different than the question), but doesn't the `PointerToRawData` field work for what you want?

Comment: @Damon i want to find offset of rsrc section by iterating through section headers

Comment: Well, since you seem to already have gotten a `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` from the section table, why not look at the offset `PointerToRawData` in the file then?

Comment: @Damon i need to know which section header belongs to resource section because i really do not need to get 'PointerToRawData' of code or data instead of resources

Comment: Well, there's a `Name` field, have you done a string compare against `.rsrc`?

Comment: because its not reliable

Answer (score 2):

First you should take a look at the following PE file specification by Microsoft: [Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)

The information you are looking for is stored in the optional header at offset 112 and is interpreted as IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY. Take a look at page 23.
This will give you the RVA (relative virtual address) and the size of the section. Interpretation of this section is explained in section 5.9. beginning at page 89.

> The RVA is the address of the table relative to the base address of
>   the image when the table is loaded.

Comment: +1, the fact that resources tend to have a separate section is an implementation detail.